# What type of components would be used to make a reliable multistage watchdog?

Tags: watchdog

The following is an example of a [multistage watchdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchdog_timer#Multistage_watchdog) from Wikipedia:-

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIJPC.jpg]

These days, there are watchdog chips like the Texas Instruments TPS3823 in the linked article that would serve for Timer Stage 1.  But what about the other stages?

---

I would have thought that ultra integrated chips would be ruled out, in favour of discrete (dumb?) components like 555 timers and transistors. They're less susceptible to crashing themselves and probably more resistant to ambient radiation. FPGAs seem to be heading towards the 'too highly integrated' camp.

Comment: If you want it more reliable you put your watchdogs in parallel.  If you want the corrective actions less agressive you put them in series, per your image.  The idea is that you have as many stages as you have levels of corrective action.  If you only have one, it's the _rightmost_ stage, and it does something brutal like reset everything.

Comment: What makes you think 555s and transistors are "more resistant to ambient radiation". This is not necessarily true at all, and depends greatly on what you mean by "ambient radiation".

Comment: @jonathanjo Yes, but I'm after finding out what **type** of components would the _rightmost_ stage be made of?  Transistors, mechanical spring, NE555 or another u controller, etc.?

Comment: Usually it's about making sure that the stages don't have the same failure modes, as opposed to being made of something "better".  Most often, nowadays, the principal failure mode of the main system is software bug; if your main system is a big complex CPU+softwarem the rightmost thing can be anything simple.  For example ATTiny with a timer program.